# HTML form submit request

Tags: php, html

What the difference with POST and REQUEST? Does it recommend if I plan to submit the whole form without the need to write parameters?

```
link.php?param=1&param=2&param=3
```

Comment: I do not understand what you are talking about. Do you mean the difference between POST and GET? I still don't understand the 2nd part of your question though

Comment: Nevermind, learn for others then.

Answer (score 4):

[$_REQUEST](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.request.php) includes [$_COOKIE](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.cookies.php), [$_GET](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php) and [$_POST](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php).

If you know the type of your request, you are best to use [$_GET](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php) or [$_POST](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php).

Comment: so if I POST from index.php to be submit to link.php, how can I get the params to retain in url address with link.php?

Comment: You do a submit your form as a GET to pass the variables through the querystring.

Comment: if you want the form to add values in the URL, you use "<form method="GET" action="blah">

Answer (score 1):

`$_POST` contains POST data, while `$_REQUEST` contains POST, query string and cookie data.

Use the specific superglobal as that way you only get data from where you expect.

Comment: so if I POST from index.php to be submit to link.php, how can I get the params to retain in url address with link.php?

Comment: If you want to pass the data to the handler for the POST request, make them hidden inputs. If you want to make the result of the POST request bookmarkable / linkable, follow the POST-Redirect-GET pattern: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get

Comment: @proyb3: I guess you should change the `<form method="post">` to `<form method="get">` is that what you want?